# Haskell - error in find/replace function

Tags: haskell

i'm making a function that takes three string values w1, w2 and s, and returns s but with all occurrences of the string w1 replaced by w2.

i have finished it, but there is an error. if w1 is only in the string s once, it works fine. but if it occurs multiple times, it doesn't work. eg:

```
Main> swapwords "turtles" "goats" "more turtles are becoming blind"
"more goats are becoming blind"
swapwords "turtles" "goats" "the blue turtles, dislike the green turtles"
"the blue turtles, dislike the green goats"
```

here is the current code:

```
split :: String -> Char -> String -> [String]
split "" _ "" = []
split "" _ r = [r]
split (x:xs) c ""
    | x == c = [[c]] ++ split xs c ""
    | otherwise = split xs c [x]
split (x:xs) c r
    | x == c = r : [[c]] ++ split xs c ""
    | otherwise = split xs c (r ++ [x])

swap :: String -> String -> [String] -> [String]
swap a b [] = []
swap a b (x:xs)
    |x==a = [b] ++ xs
    |x/=a = [x] ++ swap a b (xs)

join :: [String] -> String
join [] = ""
join (x:xs) = x ++ join (xs)

swapwords :: String -> String -> String -> String
swapwords a b "" = []
swapwords a b c = join (swap a b d)
    where d = split c ' ' []
```

if anybody knows the solution it would help me loads. thanks

Comment: First of all, just use `words` instead of `split`, it'll make your life a lot easier.  It is also a lot more efficient and idiomatic to write `b : xs` and `x : swap a b xs`.  Your `join` function is currently doing nothing more than `concat`, but I think you'd really want `unwords` if you're using `words` to split.  Give those functions a spin and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: thank you. forgot to mention - i can't use words or unwords

Comment: @simran312 - please don't vandalize the contents of your question, especially after someone's been kind enough to answer it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
swap :: String -> String -> [String] -> [String]
swap a b [] = []
swap a b (x:xs)
    |x==a = [b] ++ xs              -- <<< here
    |x/=a = [x] ++ swap a b (xs)
```

When you find the word `a`you are replacing it with `b`, but then you want to continue swapping on the remainder of the list.